# Adding a class to an element on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have a click event on one page that will add a class to an element on another page? I have tried and it seems as if because the element isn't loaded on the page it doesn't exist and can't have a class added to it.

This is a demo of what my code looks like;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#link").click(function(){
        jQuery("#element").addClass("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: Not in the manner you're attempting, no. You can only affect the DOM that's currently loaded. To do what you require you'd need to save the state of the action and then load it on the next page and amend the DOM there. You can use `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, `session`, `cookies` or an AJAX request to store data on your server to achieve this

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it

Comment: @Jonasw that's for cases where the pages are open in different tabs/windows. That may well apply here, but until the OP confirms I'd hold of closing as a dupe